# ASP.NET Core 3.1: POST-REDIRECT-GET: Passing parameters

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to implement POST-REDIRECT-GET technique where I post a JSON string to my razor OnPost method. This in turn redirects to OnGet method that takes in that string parameter. How do I hide this input parameter string to my OnGet method?

Edit: I tried using ViewData but the value is always null in my OnGet method even though I set it before redirect.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostData(string input_JSON)        
{
    TempData["InputJSON"] = input_JSON;
    return RedirectToPage("GetData");
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetGetData()
{
     string tempData = TempData["InputJSON"] as string;
    //do somethig with string;
}
```

I do form post in my javascript and when the new window opens, I see the input_string in my URL. How do I pass parameters between methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata-provider-and-session-state-cookies-arent-essential

According to Microsoft, TempData provider and session state cookies aren't essential. I had to make it essential in my Startup.cs file's ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options => {
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```